# How to debug ASP.NET MVC3 app that throws error and doesn't hit breakpoints in global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I just spent time tonight converting an existing ASP.NET webform app to MVC3 using [this guide](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/05/convert-web-forms-mvc3-how-to.html).  However, when I go to start the app just to running the app locally to check my work, I'm getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is 
temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure
that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.0.30319.237
```

I've tried setting various breakpoints in my global.asax as I suspected I screwed something up with the routing but the breakpoints aren't hit at all. Since it's not hitting my breakpoints in this file then my assumption is that I don't need to both looking at the Controller or View since that's further down the execution path.

My folder structure contains the following folders and files:

```
Controllers\
    HomeController.cs
Models\
Views\
    Home\
        Index.cshtml
    Shared\
        _Layout.cshtml
        Error.cshtml
    _ViewStart.html
    Global.asax
    web.config
web.config
```

Here's the contents of the global.asax:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace www
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //ignore aspx pages (web forms take care of these)
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
                // Parameter defaults
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
                );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

\Controllers\HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace www.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET MVC and Visual studio so not sure where to begin debugging this. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You are saying that its "global.asax" but your namespace is named as "www". How???

Comment: The name of the project is "www".

Comment: are you sure the bin is in the right directory? Ifso, are all the dll deployed?

Comment: Global.asax should not be in the Views folder, it should be in the root.

Comment: @Mystere Man: OMG, that was it. What a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a reply by Mystere Man, the answer was that `global.asax` was mistakenly put under the \Views\ folder and not in the root.  Once I moved it, all was well.